# Pandas DataFrame update and sum by matching multi-column index from another Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have

`df`  =

```
     B     TF    C   N
0  356   True  714   1
1  357   True  718   2
2  358   True  722   3
3  359   True  726   4
4  360  False  730   5
```

`lt` =

```
 B    C  
356  714    223
360  730    101
400  800    200
Name: N, dtype: int64
```

`type(lt) =>  pandas.core.series.Series`

I like to treat the series `lt`  as a multi-column lookup table

So, if keys `B` and `C` from dataframe are found exactly in the Series index,  I like to update the dataframe by summing the corresponding values of `N`.

So my final dataframe should look like:

```
       B     TF    C  N
0    356   True  714  224
1    357   True  718  2
2    358   True  722  3
3    359   True  726  4
4    360  False  730  106
```

How should I go about this?
I tried various option such as :

```
df['N'] = df['N'] + df.apply(lambda x:lt[x[['B','C']]],axis=1)
```

But it gives:

`IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Also:

```
df.apply(lambda x:lt[x.B,x.C],axis=1)
```

raises `KeyError  (357, 718)`

How should I go about this?
Thanks.

Comment: could you provide the pandas objects as code : ``df.to_dict()``

Comment: {
 'B': {0: 356, 1: 357, 2: 358, 3: 359, 4: 360},
 'TF': {0: 'True', 1: 'True', 2: 'True', 3: 'True', 4: 'False'},
 'C': {0: 714, 1: 718, 2: 722, 3: 726, 4: 730},
 'N': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is close.  Just need to fine-tune the way you map the value pair of columns `B` & `C` to the index of `lt`.  See below for details:

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), as follows:

Turn the value pair of columns `B` & `C` into tuple before mapping `lt` so that you can get the mapped values from `lt`.  For values not in `lt`, we set it to default 0 by `fillna(0)`:

```
df['N'] =  df['N'] + df[['B', 'C']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(lt).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)


     B     TF    C    N
0  356   True  714  224
1  357   True  718    2
2  358   True  722    3
3  359   True  726    4
4  360  False  730  106
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge` and `eval`:

```
out = df.merge(lt.reset_index(), on=['B', 'C'], how='left') \
        .fillna(0).eval('N = N_x + N_y') \
        .drop(columns=['N_x', 'N_y'])
```

```
>>> out
     B     TF    C      N
0  356   True  714  224.0
1  357   True  718    2.0
2  358   True  722    3.0
3  359   True  726    4.0
4  360  False  730  106.0
```

Comment: removed unnecessary column 'A'.

Comment: Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes Corralien. Your answer is absolutely correct, I had approached in a similar way, in more than single statement.  I was trying to do without adding extra columns in Data Frame.